# How can I change an ImageView's source programmaticaly

Tags: android, listview, imageview, simplecursoradapter

I have overwritten the bindView method in my custom CursorAdapter.

I need to set an image resource for each view of the ListView.

R.drawable.innervate is the name of the image in the res/drawable/ folder.

The setImageResource methods takes as a parameter only integers, however I only know the name of my resources.

How can I change the image resource of my image view if I only know the name of the resources.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) 
{

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(1));

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.innervate);       
}
```

The data of the image resource is taken from a cursor. So, I'm retrieving the names of the pictures from my database and the pictures are in my res/drawable/ folder.

Comment: How do you know what image you want to use? Where is this data stored?

Comment: The drawable is located in the res/drawable/ folder. I don't know the integer id of the resource, but I know its name. For example : innervate.png ; moonfire.png ;

Comment: How do you know its name? Where is that data stored in the code for your app?

Comment: The method cursor.getString(0) would return the name of the drawable resource. However, the method cursor.getString(0) would return a string and the method setImageResource only takes as an argument the Integer id of the drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawableName", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Here is an example of a static method that you can use to get the `resource id` of any drawable that you know it's name. (Must be in the res/drawable folders)

```
public static int getDrawableId(Context context, String nameOfDrawable) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfDrawable, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

So an example using my method above:

```
imageView.setImageResource(getDrawableId(this, "innervate"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). This method is often abused when using `R.id` is more appropriate, but I think you have a legitimate reason to use it here.